# WPF под Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-xp

Как заставить запустить WPF программу под XP? Пробовал ставить .net framework, жалуется "винда старая".

Comment: Какую именно версию фреймворка вы пытались устанавливать и какая версия вашей Винды (в частности интересуют сервис-паки)? Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Comment: ставил под пак 3, 4.6 версию фрэймвока

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF требует версию фреймворка 3.0 и выше. При этом под XP [можно поставить](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx) максимум версию 4.0. Соответственно пробуйте поставить что-то из 3.0/3.5/4.0. Возможно еще потребуется наличие установленного SP2.

Comment: Хорошо, в понедельник проверю.

Comment: всё, запустил. Спасибо, от души )

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy не за что!